# docker - add extra_hosts with name instead of IP

Tags: docker

I'd like to add a resolved domain name to my `/etc/hosts` file on a Docker container. I see that with `extra_hosts` in `docker-compose.yml` file I can achieve this however I am not being permitted to add a domain name, only an IP address.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    extra_hosts:
      - "192.168.65.2:api.test"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    network_mode: bridge
```

However when I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: for backoffice_web_1  Cannot create container for service web: b'invalid IP address in add-host: "api.test"'

ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: b'invalid IP address in add-host: "api.test"'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I can manually add the entry to `/etc/hosts` and everything works as expected, so I'm unsure why Docker is not permitting what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: The [Docker Compose YAML documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts) suggests you have the name and IP address in the wrong order.

Comment: It should be `api.test:192.168.65.2`

Comment: Indeed I have! Thank you both - I had incorrectly assumed that the order would be the same as what appears in `/etc/hosts` file.